# i need help to create a simple YouTube_downloader

Tags: tkinter, python-multithreading, pytube

I want to create youtube_downloader in tkinter. I want to use the "threading" module to do the video download in the background. But I can't find a way to cancel the download once it's started

```
from pytube import YouTube
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import Tk,Button,Entry,StringVar

class app(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry("400x300")
        self.title('YouTube downloader')

        self.url=StringVar()
        self.url_input=Entry(self,textvariable=self.url)
        self.url_input.pack()

        self.btn_ok=Button(self,text='download',command=Thread(target=self.download).start)
        self.btn_ok.pack()

        self.btn_cannel=Button(self,text='cannel downloading',command=self.cannel_download)

    def download(self):
        try:
            yt=YouTube(self.url.get())
            print('downloading...')
            yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    

    def cannel_download(self):
        # I don't know what to write in this section
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    app().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the option is to use `on_progress_callback` option of `YouTube()` to cancel the download inside the callback by raising exception:

```py
class app(Tk):
    ...

    def download(self):
        try:
            # register a callback that will be executed during download
            yt = YouTube(self.url.get(), on_progress_callback=self.on_progress)
            print('downloading...')
            self.abort_download = False  # flag to abort download
            yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

    def on_progress(self, *args):
        # last argument is the remaining bytes
        print("progress:", args[-1])
        if self.abort_download:
            # raise exception to cancel the download
            raise Exception("cancel download") # can be any string

    def cannel_download(self):
        # set the abort download flag
        self.abort_download = True

    ...
```

Comment: the method you mention takes some time is there any other module to replace the "threading" class

Comment: It is not issue on `threading`, it is how `pytube` is designed and working.